# "ValueError: could not convert string to float" when converting input

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Recently I have been working on a code and got stuck for days on this error.
Basically the program calculates how many calories you have to eat everyday. I have to take input from an entry and I don't know how to convert that input(it's a string by default) into a float to start using the numbers.
I am using Python 3 with Tkinter.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x500")
root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
root.title("BMI Calculator")

def calc(args):

    def BMI_temp(args):
        print(str(boyage))
        BMI = IntVar()
        BMI = 66.5 + (13.75 * float(boykg)) + (5.003 * float(boycm)) - (6.755 * float(boyage))
        bmi_temp = Label(root, text="This is how many calories you have to eat if you have a non-active life: " + str(float(BMI)))
        bmi_temp.grid(row=3, sticky=W)

    def boy_age_fnct(args):
        boy_age_entry.focus_set()
        boy_cm_entry.delete(0, "end")
        boy_age.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
        boy_age_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        boy_age_entry.bind("<Return>", BMI_temp)

    def boy_cm_fnct(args):
        boy_cm_entry.focus_set()
        boy_kg_entry.delete(0, "end")
        boy_cm.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        boy_cm_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        boy_cm_entry.bind("<Return>", boy_age_fnct)

    boy_kg_entry.focus_set()
    temp = boygirle.get()
    gender = temp.title()
    welcome.destroy()
    hello_lbl.destroy()
    boygirle.destroy()
    boygirlq.destroy()

    if gender[0] == 'B':
        boy_kg.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        boy_kg_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        boy_kg_entry.bind("<Return>", boy_cm_fnct)

    boyage = boy_age_entry.get()
    boycm = boy_cm_entry.get()
    boykg = boy_kg_entry.get()

def hello(args):
    name_user = name_entry.get()
    name2 = name_user.title()
    name_entry.delete(0, "end")
    hello = "Hello " + name2 + "!"
    hello_lbl["text"] = hello
    hello_lbl.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    btn_cont.grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    name.destroy()
    name_entry.destroy()
    btn_cont.focus_set()

def BMI():
    btn_cont.destroy()
    boygirlq.grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    boygirle.grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=35)
    boygirle.bind("<Return>", calc)
    boygirle.focus_set()

welcome = Label(root, text="Hello! This is a BMR calculator. It tells you how many calories you have to eat!", font="System 14 bold")
name = Label(root, text="Please enter your name:", font="System 12")
hello_lbl = Label(root, font="System 14")
boygirlq = Label(root, text="Are you a boy or a girl?", font="System 12 bold")
boy_kg = Label(root, text="Please enter your weight(in kg):", font="System 12 bold")
boy_cm = Label(root, text="Please enter your height(in cm):", font="System 12")
boy_age = Label(root, text="Please enter your age(in years):", font="System 12")

btn_cont = Button(root, text="Continue", font="Helvetica 12", command=BMI, relief=RAISED)

boy_kg_entry = Entry(root, font="System 12", relief=SUNKEN)
boy_cm_entry = Entry(root, font="System 12", relief=SUNKEN)
boy_age_entry = Entry(root, font="System 12", relief=SUNKEN)
name_entry = Entry(root, font="System 12", relief=SUNKEN)
boygirle = Entry(root, font="System 12", relief=SUNKEN)
name_entry.bind("<Return>", hello)
name_entry.focus_set()

welcome.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, ipadx=200)
name.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
name_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried all the methods I found on the internet but nothing worked.

Comment: That error is caused by calling `float()` on a value that cannot be converted to a float.  If you look closely at the error message, it should display the bad value, i.e. something like `ValueError: could not convert string to float: apple`.  If it just ends with `float:`, that means the input was blank.

Comment: I understand and I know that. I think I should place the `boyage` `boycm` and `boykg` somewhere else but where. I know that the error is because the entry is not completed. What should I do?

Comment: Your `calc()` function should specifically check each value beforehand, and exit if any of the values can't be converted to floats.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try to fix it

Comment: As explained in the answer, `ValueError: could not convert string to float` can occur when reading a dataframe from a `csv` file and casting types `df = df[['p']].astype({'p': float})`. If the csv was recorded with empty spaces, python will not recognize the space characters. You need to overwrite empty cells with `NaN` using `df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Probable cause: you forgot to fill out one field

### Explanation

a [float](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) *can* be constructed from a str, it just has to have the right format.
You should be able to convert strings that look like floats to floats by just using `float(mystr)`.

Pay attention to:

- No spaces (or non-digit characters)
- Period (`.`) as decimal separator, not comma (`,`)
- *some* special things are allowed (e.g. `inf`, `5e3`,
  ...)

Most probably (if you didn't cut anything off your error message), you forgot to fill out one field and are thus trying to perform `float('')`.

### Some examples

```
>>> float('')  # probably your case
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#74>", line 1, in <module>
    float('')
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
>>> float('1')
1.0
>>> float('1.0')
1.0
>>> float('no number')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
    float('no number')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'no number'
>>> float('10e30')
1e+31
>>> float('inf')
inf
>>> float('123.456')
123.456
>>> float('123,456')  # , not allowed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
    float('123,456')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '123,456'
>>> float('123 456')  # no whitespace as separator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#69>", line 1, in <module>
    float('123 456')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '123 456'
```

### Further thoughts

An alternative for getting the float values is asking for them in a popup window -- this can be done with `tkinter.simpledialog.askfloat`. This will return you a `float` directly and show an error message if the string entered could not be converted.
**But**, it may also return `None` when the user clicks the "Cancel" button, so you might want to check the result before computing stuff.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.simpledialog import askfloat

def click():
    val = askfloat('Title', 'The prompt:')  # float or None (cancel)
    if val is not None:
        tk.Label(root, text=f'The value "{val}" is a valid float').pack()  # f-string, replace with `'The value "{}" is ...'.format(val)` if you get an error (Python < 3.6)

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text='Click!', command=click).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**Edit:**

If you keep the `Entry` widgets, you may want to catch the error and show the user a message. This can easily be done with `tkinter.mesagebox`, specifically of this case the `showerror` function.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror

def click():
    try:
        val = float(entry.get())
    except ValueError as e:
        showerror('Error title', 'The number could not be converted to float:\n'+str(e))
    else:
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        Label(root, text=val).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
tk.Label(root, text='insert a float value below:').pack()
entry.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='and click!', command=click).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know what I have to do.

Comment: You're welcome. You may also want to look into tkinter.messagebox

Comment: This solved my problem. I'm pulling data from an API and it turns out that I was receiving a single '' empty string back that couldn't be converted. A quick try except bypassed it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

people looking for pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('./file.csv', decimal=',')
```

or

```
df = df.replace(",", '.', regex=True)
```